# Basic Jquery Slider (script issue I think)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I used the slider from this site http://www.basic-slider.com/, and installed it as shown, however i think the initating script for the slider is arguing or conflicting against another script I have installed on the page for animated div movments.

I When i load the page i get everything the slider should have numbers, navigation controls, spacing etc. But no images, whatso ever. I have checed the urls for the images and they are all linked in correctly. All the list elements or slides are correct. as far as I can see its either, a script issue or it has somthing to do with the postioning on the page because the page was built using relative positioning and ALOT of percentage values.

** Slider Css **

```
ul.bjqs {
    position: relative;
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:none;
}
li.bjqs-slide {
    position:absolute ;
    display:none;
}  
ul.bjqs-controls {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    z-index:9999;
}   
ul.bjqs-controls.v-centered li a {
    position:absolute;
}    
ul.bjqs-controls.v-centered li.bjqs-next a {
    right:0;
}    
ul.bjqs-controls.v-centered li.bjqs-prev a {
    left:0;
}    
ol.bjqs-markers {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width:100%;
}    
ol.bjqs-markers.h-centered {
    text-align: center;
}    
ol.bjqs-markers li {
    display:inline;
}   
ol.bjqs-markers li a {
    display:inline-block;
}   
p.bjqs-caption {
    display:block;
    width:96%;
    margin:0;
    padding:2%;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
```

** HTML **

```
<div id="slides">                       
The ul list sits in here with li img src /li. (sorry couldnt get lists to work in the editor. :(                                                        
</div>
```

** Conflicting scripts **

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
                        $(document).ready(function() {
                                $('#p-load').hide().delay(500).fadeIn("slow");
                        });
                        </script>  

                <!-- ꜜꜜ slider ꜜꜜ -->
                <script class="secret-source">
                jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

                      $('#slides').bjqs({
                        animtype      : 'slide',
                        automatic     : 'true',
                        height        : 320,
                        width         : 720,
                        responsive    : true,
                        randomstart   : true,
                        showmarkers   : false
                      });

                    });
                </script>
```

The script above the slider script initiates the page div animations.

Comment: ive never seen a class attribute on a script tag before

Comment: I thought the same thing, but it works in the demo...

Comment: and when you comment out the line "$("#p-load")..." it works as desired ?

Comment: yes... but i have moved away from this tool now, and located somthing else. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it could be a z-index issue. Are you sure that the z-index's are set up correctly?

Comment: I added a Z-index, to the main ul element, for the slider. Still no progress... :(

Answer (score 0):

As you are using the reponsive mode, maybe you should try to trigger a window resize. I had a problem like this and this worked for me.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).trigger('resize');
});
```